# After Migration Oracle database into SQL Server 2016 facing problem in VB 6.0 application

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

In existing vb and oracle connection it showing details error without handling

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 826
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 32
ORA-06512: at "EST.D_SQL", line 13
ORA-06512: at "EST.P_VAL_C", line 512
ORA-06512: at "EST.P_EST_MAIN", line 29
ORA-06512: at "EST.P_EST_C", line 31
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

but After Migration Oracle database into SQL Server 2016 facing problem in VB 6.0 application i.e. Some kind of error occurs in back end stored procedure that will not showing in front end application is this problem of driver which is use connection or else

```
In sql server & VB 6.0 application using : Provider='sqloledb'

In oracle & VB 6.0 application using : Provider=MSDASQL' DSN Connection

in some procedure if i execute procedure in SSMS it's showing error like


> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure p1no, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 45]  
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

but in vb application when i execute from front end showing like given below and not showing main procedure or sub procedure name and line no.

> Run-time error -2147xxxxxxx  
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Please help

Comment: You have substantially changed your question from what it was originally. Please post your updated question (about Oracle vs. MSSQL Server error messages) as **a new separate question** and revert this question to your original posting (regarding how to get details from MSSQL error messages in VB6).

Answer (score 1):

VB6's error handling does not forward details of SQL Server errors, it only gives you the HRESULT (the `-2147...` number) and the human-readable error message.

To get more details from a SQL Server error in VB6 (and VBA, and to an extent VBScript) follow this article:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/167957/info-extracting-error-information-from-ado-in-vb
>
> Extracting Error Information from ADO in VB

Use the `.Errors` collection of your `ADODB.Connection` object.

VB6 doesn't support `try/catch/finally` but it does have `On Error Goto...` which will suffice:

```vb
' Ensure ADO is a referenced library instead of using late-bound objects.

Sub RunMe()

    Dim c As Connection
    Set c = New Connection()

    On Error GoTo CatchAdoError ' This is roughly equivalent to a `try` statement, except much worse.

    c.ConnectionString = "..."

    Call DoSomething c

    ' No error happened, so return immediately so execution doesn't enter the `CatchAdoError` label's block
    Exit Sub

CatchAdoError:

    ' Iterate through the error details:
    Dim errorDetails As String
    errorDetails = ""

    For Each adoError In c.Errors

        errorDetails = errorDetails adoError.Description & vbCrLf
        errorDetails = errorDetails adoError.Source & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    Next

    Call MsgBox errorDetails

End Sub

Sub DoSomething( c As Connection )

    ' Your main logic goes here

End Sub
```

Comment: but in existing oracle and vb application showing detail error without handling like  ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 826
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 32
ORA-06512: at "EST.D_SQL", line 13
ORA-06512: at "EST.P_VAL_C", line 512
ORA-06512: at "EST.P_EST_MAIN", line 29
ORA-06512: at "EST.P_EST_C", line 31
ORA-06512: at line 2

Comment: @TusharK Those are Oracle-specific errors, not MSSQL Server errors. Oracle and MSSQL return different error message formats entirely.